# Remove read only permission from folder for files to upload in a destination folder (php)

Tags: php, file-upload, upload, directory, shared-directory

I have a php script to upload file to a folder in my locahost. The folder permission is read only. I belive that is the reason why file is not getting uploaded. I tried changing the permission using following commands,

```
attrib -r c:\wamp64\*.* /s

attrib -r +s c:\wamp64\www\ProjectName\platform\tabs\uploads
```

But the folder is still read only. I cannot figure what can be the issue other than this that upload is not working. Any suggestions are helpful. The same code works fine on other server, but not on localhost. uploads folder in server has all permissions.

Comment: It looks like the operating system is windows based, can you give us more info on the system, and the account permissions you have on it?

Comment: Have you right clicked on the folder, gone to "Properties/Security" and tried changing the permissions that way?

Answer (score 0):

Under Windows, the command `ATTRIB` is generally used to change permissions on files... not on folders. If you want to change the folder permissions, you have to use `CACLS` or `ICACLS` as follows:

```
CACLS "C:\wamp64\www\ProjectName\platform\tabs\uploads" /e /p MyUsername:F
ICACLS "C:\wamp64\www\ProjectName\platform\tabs\uploads" /grant MyUsername:F
```